# Weblogic domain and cluster creation with WLST

Tags: python, weblogic, jython, wlst

I want to create a cluster with 2 managed servers on 2 different physical machines.

I have following tasks to be performed (please correct me if I miss something)

1. Domain creation.
2. Set admin server properties and create AdminServer under SSL
3. Create logical machines for the physical ones
4. Create managed servers
5. create cluster with the managed servers

I have following questions.

1. Which of the above mentioned tasks can be done offline if any ?
2. Which of the above mentioned tasks must also be performed on the 2nd physical machine ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually found the answer. I am posting here for reference.

Out of the 5 mentioned tasks, all can be performed with an offline wlst script. All of them have to be performed on the node where AdminServer is supposed to live.

Now, for updating the domain information on the second node, there is an nmEnroll command in wlst which hast to be performed **online**

So, to summarize,

1. Execute an offline wlst script to perform all the 5 tasks mentioned in the question. This has to be done on the node (physical computer) where we want our AdminServer to run.
2. Start nodemanager on all the nodes to be used in the cluster,
3. Start the AdminServer on the node where we executed the domain creation script.
4. On all the other nodes execute the script which looks like following.

   connect('user','password','t3://adminhost:adminport')

   nmEnroll('path_to_the_domain_dir')

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps missed after the step 1, you need to copy the configuration from the machine where the AdminServer is running run to the other machine in the cluster using the command pack content in Weblogic installation:

1.1 On the machine where the AdminServer is running run `./pack.shdomain=/home/oracle/config/domains/my_domain
    -template=/home/oracle/my_domain.jar -template_name=remote_managed -managed=true`

1.2 Go on the other machines and copy the jar file produced in the previous step  and run `./unpack.sh -domain=/home/oracle/config/domains/my_domain -template=/home/oracle/my_domain.jar SAML_IDP_FromScript`

Now you have copied all the file you need to start the NodeManager and the ManagedServers on the other machines.